# Mysql select from multiple rows in one query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this Mysql database table (that stores some settings for my app):

```
Table name: settings

id    param_name    param_value
--------------------------------
1     ringtone      12.mp3
2     user          nick
3     email         nick@example.com
4     location      Athens, Greece
5     phone         0123456789
6     time_offset   GMT+3
```

The "id" column is just auto-incremental and gets value from mysql.

The column "param_name" has some initial values (such as: ringtone, user ...etc)

The column "param_value" takes it's values dynamically from a "settings" form so that each parameter has it's unique value.

I want to select these all rows with one query and turn each one of them into a variable such as:

```
$this_ringtone = "12.mp3";
$this_user = "nick";
$this_email = "nick@example.com";
$this_location = "Athens, Greece";
$this_phone = "0123456789";
$this_time_offset = "GMT+3";
```

I can do that with multiple queries but since the rows are actually a lot more, I would prefer a single mysqli query.

Comment: Is what you have shown above the structure of your table and of the data? There appears to be no way to identify which field belongs with which record - unless an individual user's record happens to occupy 6 rows every time

Comment: The table "settings" is exactly as shown above. I can do for example: "SELECT param_value FROM settings WHERE param_name = 'ringtone' ... Then I can retrieve the corresponding "param_value" of each "param_name"... But that takes one query per row... I would prefer to get them all in a single query.

Comment: you need to change your structure to get specific user if there are multiple entries with same parameter

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of hard to achieve the way you want, as the name of the column is the same for all values - but there are different values you want into specific variables. You should instead flip the table, so it looks something like this

```
| ID  | ringtone | user | email            | location | phone | time_offset |
+-----+----------+------+------------------+----------+-------+-------------+
|  1  | 12.mp3   | nick | nick@example.com | Greece   | 12345 | UTC+3       |
|  2  | 25.mp3   | joe  | joe@example.com  | France   | 54321 | UTC+3       |
+-----+----------+------+------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

You can now use a code such as below

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $id             = $row['id'];
    $ringtone       = $row['ringtone'];
    $user           = $row['user'];
    ...
    ...
    $time_offset    = $row['time_offset'];
}
```

...and so on. This is because you fetch the value of the cell based on the *name* of the column, in your case those are only `param_name` and `param_value`. So you can't really know when you should put then into the proper variables, unless the table is static (never changes, so you can hard-code it - bad practice) or there are always 6 rows for each user - but if that's the case, you're easier off doing a structure as shown as above anyway.

**Note** that if you have different rows of values with the structure above, you'd only get the last one this way (as we select everything, and put that into variables for each row). So for this example, you'd only get the `id: 2` and France-guy (and never `id: 1`, or Greece-guy, so if you have many lines, your query should be different. This is because `id: 2` was the last row in the table.

---

Even more elegantly, you can use the PHP function `extract()`, like this

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
extract($row); // Extract the values of the array into a variable of its own
echo $user; // Name of variable is the same as the column in the database
```

Hope this provided some clear guidance on how your table-structure should look like.

---

**UPDATE**
Right, so for whatever reason you *don't* want the table-structure above, with the use of *variable variables*, you'd only need one query. Something like this

```
$values = array();
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ${$row['param_name']} = $row['param_value'];
}
echo $ringtone;
```

This creates a variable with the name of the value in `$row['param_name']`, and that variable has the value of `$row['param_value']`. Was actually a lot easier to achieve than I thought.

If you want the variable-name to be `$this_name`, simply use `${"this_".$row['param_name']} = $row['param_value'];`

You should have your `param_name` column set to *unique* in the database, to avoid variables being overwritten.

Comment: Using `extract()` is an excellent idea. You can read about it here. http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: Plus on for this working example, but that was a table layout that I wanted to avoid using. Actually, that's what I had in mind initially -since I have used this procedure several times... However in the settings table I wanted this simple: param_name->param_value layout. I have posted an answer to my own question explaining how I (finally!!!) did it... If you have any comments on it, I will be glad to hear them. Thank you for your time. T.

Comment: @OllieJones Seems like, that some people don't think so: https://dzone.com/articles/php-bad-practice-use-extract

Comment: @OllieJones : I just tried that and is not working :( Ajax returns an undefined variable (ringtone)... The errors are: "PHP Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given" and -consequently- "PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: ringtone in..."

Answer (score 0):

Just select all the rows using the * selector..

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table");
while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC){
       $ringtone = $row['ringtone'];
       $user = $row['user'];
}
```

If you wanted to build them into an array..

```
$one = array();

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");
    $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table");
    while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC){
           $one['ringtone'] = $row['ringtone'];
           $one['user'] = $row['user'];
    }
```

Comment: Is not working... Well there is a second parenthesis missing after MYSQLI_ASSOC) -must be: MYSQLI_ASSOC))... Even when I fix that, I get "Undefined variable: ringtone"

Comment: The table "settings" is exactly as shown above. I can do for example: "SELECT param_value FROM settings WHERE param_name = 'ringtone' ... Then I can retrieve the corresponding "param_value" of each "param_name"... But that takes one query per row... I would prefer to get them all in a single query.

Comment: You'll get *Undefined variable* errors when doing this, as you have specified the value of the cell, not the name of it (in this case, "param_name" and "param_value"). If the table structure was flipped, you'd be correct.

Comment: @Qirel: any suggestions even with a different table structure? can you please post a full answer?

Comment: Using the structure provided in the other answer would be the ideal solution. Then you could select all the variables by using the query [code]"Select * from settings where id = $id[/code]   Then, like I posted in the other answer (or using extract as noted by the other use) you can get all the variables for that specific row

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with it a bit more, I came to a working solution:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_pass", "database");
$query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM settings");

$result = array();
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($query)){
    $param_name = $row1[2];
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conni, "SELECT `param_value` FROM ".DB_TABLE_PREFIX."settings WHERE param_name = '$param_name' ");
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
    $result[] = array($param_name => $row2["param_value"]);
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

Now, I get this array that I can use in my app:

```
[{"ringtone":"12.mp3"},{"user":"nick"},{"email":"nick@example.com"},{"location":"Athens, Greece"},{"phone":"0123456789"},{"time_offset":"GMT+3"}]
```

Thank you all very much for your time and answers. T.